# C# Windows Service - Packaging Binaries

Tags: c#, windows, service, tfs

I have created a C# service that uses the TFS DLLs for connecting and querying a server instance. I have been able to run the service code in debug on visual studio, it complies and runs without issue on my development machine.

Once I install the build output service.exe and the associated files, and deploy in on a host server using installutil I get a success message from installutil, but the service fails to start, it is set to run automatic.

When I try a manual start, I get the error message "1053 The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion"

My assumption is that the dll files are not properly placed despite being copied over with the service.exe

Is there a specific way to deploy these files as part of installutil? I cannot find specific documentation or guidance on providing the necessary support files.

Thanks.

Comment: Two thoughts; if your startup is taking too long, you will get that error. I'd put in more logging to help diagnose where the problem is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could install the [TFS SDK](http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/downloads/tfs-sdks/) on the target.

Or, you could add the appropriate [TFS Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=team%20foundation%20server) to your project.

Also, you may consider using the newer [TFS REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/overview)?

Comment: I ended up install the SDK, and Team Viewer, this provided all the files I needed. I'm going to look into the Rest API as an more tightly woven alternative.